# Supermicro X9DRT-HF+ board won't power on (hw switch defunct) after IPMI setting changed in BIOS [solved]

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, supermicro, ipmi

I have a bunch of used Supermicro X9DRT-HF+ boards with dual Xeon and 128GB RAM.

They came with IPMI settings to use static IP addresses.

I changed the settings in BIOS under IPMI->"BMC Network Configuration"->"Update IPMI LAN Configuration" from "No" to "Yes". After that I changed "Configuration Address Source" from "Static" to "DHCP".

So far so good... but instead of rebooting and THEN changing the "Update IPMI LAN Configuration" back to "No" (wich is recommended in the manual), I switched back to the "No" setting immediately and then rebooted the machine.

After that the board never came back on again...

Later, I found out that I could set a Jumper (JPB1) to completely disable IPMI. With that the board boots fine, but... I really need the IPMI feature working again.

(edit) I also tried to reset via "ipmicfg -fde" from an running Linux system. But that didn't work because the IPMI was completely disabled via jumper. (/edit)

As I said. With the jumper back to IPMI "enable" the board won't even power on anymore :-(

Any ideas how to completely reset the IPMI?

[Solved] After removing the on board battery for a couple of hours. I enabled IPMI via jumper again and was able to boot into BIOS settings again. This time all IPMI settings were on default. Everything fine now. Thanks for the help though. [/Solved]

Comment: If the answer from [Resetting Supermicro IPMI interface](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/314643-resetting-supermicro-ipmi-interface) works, you could write up your own answer here.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for the link, but I already tried the reset via "ipmicfg-win.exe -fde" from a Linux console on the running system. It does not work, because the board would only boot with IPMI disabled via jumper. When I tried the above command, I got the a message saying something about "no BMC available". So this way of resetting didn't work :-(

Comment: Did you try the BMC cold reset as shown in the [PDF user guide](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/utility/IPMICFG/Supermicro_Utility_User_Guide_IPMICFG.pdf)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I will try it today. Will post result here.